# Access values within '<>' sign

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a gesture recognizer that looks like this:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var currentImage = sender.view
    print(currentImage)

}
```

And prints out this:

```
Optional(<UIImageView: 0x7ff72601ddd0; frame = (0 0; 414 414); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000b541e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000005be0c0>>)
```

How do I get the value of `UIImageView` in `sender.view`?

P.S.

The code that calls the tap recognizer looks like this:

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
if let  currentImage = sender.view as? UIImageView {

}
```

OR directly if 100 % sure

```
let  currentImage = sender.view as! UIImageView
```

OR

```
guard let currentImage = sender.view as? UIImageView else { return }
/// then use unwrapped currentImage
```